# Cross-domain AJAX call returning string JSON, instead of JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am making a cross-domain AJAX call, and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or the providers of the API call is incorrectly returning the JSON. Whenever I get the response from the API call, it is a string instead of a JSON object. Here is my AJAX call.

```
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://cross-domain/getSummaryStat.action',
        data: { minDailyDate: start_param, maxDailyDate: end_param },
        success: function(response) {
            map = {
                gamefuse: response["ROM-GF-Live"],
                facebook: response["ROM-FB-Live"],
                kongregate: response["ROM-Kongregate-Live"],
                yahoo: response["ROM-Yahoo-Live"]
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
           alert('request failed');
        }
    });
```

When the response comes back, here is response.result

```
"[{"dayRetention1":"0.01453800063053","visit":"601","installs":"203"},{"dayRetention1":"0.122484891199019","visit":"33863","installs":"10949"]"
```

NOTE: I set dataType to `jsonp` because it is a cross-domain AJAX call, and I was getting an error without it.

Comment: What makes you think that the provider supports JSONP responses in the first place?

Comment: When I set `dataType: json` the `error` callback gets set. When i set it to `jsonp`, I actually get a result

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp'` doesn't *magically* make cross-domain requests work.  The server needs to support it; it needs to return `callback({json: ['data']})`.

Answer (score 0):

First, It looks like the returned string isn't even in correct JSON form.  It's missing a close bracket at the end.

If this doesn't fix it then the issue here is probably on the server side.  Since JSONP is JSON with padding, your return function shouldn't be:

```
function_name("the string that I return");
```

Instead you should have:

```
function_name({
    "name":"Bob Loblaw", 
    "age":40
});
```